# SendMessage function in php_serial_class

Tags: php, serial-port, sms

I'm using php_serial_class and php to send SMS with a simple code like this:

```
                 $serial->sendMessage("AT+cmgf=1;+cnmi=2,1,0,1,0\r");
                 $serial->sendMessage("at+cmgs=\"$send_phone\"\r");
                 $serial->sendMessage("$message");
                 $serial->sendMessage(chr(26));
```

How if I wish to know the message is sent out or not?

I tried this but not working...`if(!$serial->sendMessage())`..

Is there any other ways?Thank you.

Comment: It's not working because that method returns no result flag. You'll probably have to find something to read from the serial port and check for an `OK` response from the modem.

Comment: @mario Thanks for your reply.I tried to read the serial_class file,but still don't know how to get send message responce from the modem...

Comment: It's an awful class (which is why it's hosted on phpclasses). What you are looking for is probably `readPort()`. Need to break out last line, if any, trim, and compare it against `"OK"` / alternatively regex comparison.

Comment: @mario Oh yes,I can use this method.Thank you so much mario,you should put this comment as answer so that I can set it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to mario.

I can use trim `readPort()` to get the response whether it's OK or ERROR.